# Intellij Idea how to add maven to existing no-standard layout module?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-3

This project is downloaded from Subversion.It's not a maven project and it's not using maven standard directory layout.
I want to add maven to it but keep its directory layout.But once I add maven to it , the ide automatically change its layout to standard.
The ide version 2018.2 and maven version is 3.5.3

Comment: This is just a comment, but you will probably make your life easier if you use the standard layout...

Comment: @JFMeier Agreed,but it's not really up to me.This is a practice project and I'm the only one using maven in the team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy, but I strongly recommend you to refactor your project to the standard layout for the future.

You'll just need to add the config to your pom.xml

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>java</sourceDirectory>
</build>
```

It's screenshot with custom layout:

[image]

Comment: Thanks，I manually created the pom file using your config,and import the module as a maven project,and it worked.